# iOS "info.plist"

Tags: xcode, ios, iphone

Добрый день, изучаю iOS^ и сейчас пытаюсь засунуть значение в Plist файл но ничего не выходит.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];
[plistDict setValue:@"over" forKey:@"over"];
[plistDict writeToFile:finalPath atomically: YES];
NSLog(@"the value is %@",plistDict);
```

Вот мой код, подскажите что тут неверно ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не можете писать в бандл.

Чтобы сохранить файл в плист нужно писать его в другое место, что-то вроде

```
NSString *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.plist"];
...
```

У каждого приложения есть своя "песочница", и они могу писать только туда.

Детальнее [здесь](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html), пункт `The App Sandbox`

Comment: спасибо! Помогло!